# react-router Link doesn't render href attribute with server side rendering?

Tags: express, reactjs, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

I have a expressjs  app with the following code, what i am trying to do is to render a react component named **Hello** with the request to "/". Inside Hello component i am using two react-router Links, but these two Links doesn't render the href attributes.

I am using here react-router 2

**Server.js file**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var React = require("react");
var ReactDOM = require("react-dom/server");

var Hello = React.createFactory(require("./js/components/Hello"));
// The above is a reference to pre-compiled Hello.jsx to Hello.js using babel

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", "./views");

app.use(express.static("./public"));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.render("Home",{data:ReactDOM.renderToString(Hello())});
});


app.listen(app.get("port"), function () {
    console.log("server started on port " + app.get("port"));
});
```

**Hello.jsx File**

```
var React = require("react");
var Link = require("react-router/lib/Link");

var Hello = React.createClass({
   callMe:function(){
       alert("Hurray");
   },
   componentWillMount:function(){
        console.log("componentWillMount fired");
   },
   render:function(){
     //  console.log(this);
       return(
           <div>
                <h2 onClick={this.callMe}>Hello Boom Boom {this.props.name}</h2>
                <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                <Link to="/about">About</Link>
                // above two Links rendering anchor tags without href attribute
           </div>
       );
   }
});


module.exports = Hello;
```

**Home.ejs File**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <h2>Welcome to home page</h2>
    <div id="container">
        <%- data %>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: in browser output]

Answer (score 2):

Please consult the React Router server rendering guide: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ServerRendering.md

You need to render your components in an appropriate routing context for `<Link>` to generate URLs.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting server rendering guide, but I hardly be able to understand that . can you please suggest me some sample code of using react router 2 with express ?

Comment: The server rendering example _is_ a stylized example of what to do with Express. You need to use the `match()` helper and render a `<RouterContext>` on the server.

Comment: @taion your link is broken

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same problem, and the thing I was missing was the surrounding `<RouterContext>`. `<Link>` components seem to have an empty `href` attribute when not inside of a `<Router>` or appropriate `react-router` environment. I improved the routing in the SSR code (I was doing a [weird partial solution](https://github.com/opensessions/opensessions/blob/6a08c9cb544df43cc0cd065eb9c4d23e131fbcb6/server/src/server.js)) and the links started appearing.